# Magento 1.9 check if order got shipment

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, email, email-templates, transactional-mail

I want to load a specific block in the transactional email only when the order is shipped. I want to load the block, buy using the following code:

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/invoiceemailhead.phtml' order=$order}}
```

I already use that template to check the paymentmethod, but using;

```
<?php if($this->getOrder()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=='cashondelivery'):?>
```

How can I also check if a order is shipped? What code do I need for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using below code to check if the order has shipped.

```
<?php $hasShipment = $this->getOrder()->getShipmentsCollection()->count();
if($hasShipment){
    .... // Do your stuff
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the order is completely shipped, the following function could help:

```
/**
 * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order
 * @return boolean
 */
protected function isOrderCompletelyShipped(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
{
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getParentItemId()) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($item->getQtyShipped() !== $item->getQtyOrdered()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```